# Use Parameter Store parameters in EC2 UserData in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameter-passing, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch an EC2 Windows instance using Cloudformation, where using the EC2 UserData in PowerShell format I need to add a service user account to the local Administrators and later install some apps. I want to use a AWS Parameter Store parameter in the EC2 user data to pass credentials.

I am defining the parameter store value as CFT parameter:

```
Parameters:
    ServiceUserEmail:
      Type: String
      Default: '{{resolve:ssm-secure:serviceuser-email:1}}'
      Description: Service User Email
```

And try to call the parameter as following:

```
 UserData:         
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          <powershell>
          # Add Sevice account as Administrator
          Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "${ServiceUserEmail}"
          </powershell>
          <persist>true</persist>
```

For some reason the placeholder ${ServiceUserEmail} gets replaced with the actual string '{{resolve:ssm-secure:serviceuser-email:1}}' but not the value behind it in the parameter store.

I have also tried the command without the placeholder with no success:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "'{{resolve:ssm-secure:serviceuser-email:1}}'"
```

The command needs to look the following after passing the parameter:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "serviceuseremail@domain.com"
```

Could you advise please?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. unfortunately it is not working for me still. the placeholder gets replaced by the parameter, but the parameter is not resolving into its value still:
 2022/01/24 13:27:57Z: Message: The errors from user scripts: Add-LocalGroupMember : Principal {{resolve:ssm:serviceuser-email:1}} was
not found.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\UserScript.ps1:8 char:1
+ Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "{{resolve:ssm:s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I have tried both ssm and ssm-secure parameters

Comment: okay, solved. when defining the Parameter the type has to be AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String> instead of just 'String'. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, solved. when defining the Parameter the type has to be AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value< String>

instead of just String

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I still just get the literal '{{resolve:ssm-secure:serviceuser-email:1}}' returned...

Comment: Can you share how to use it in user data? From this AWS docs, EC2 is not in the supported list. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormaton/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm-secure-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I think the full array form of [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) should work. Something along these lines:

```
 UserData:         
        Fn::Base64: 
         Fn::Sub:
           - <powershell>
             # Add Sevice account as Administrator
             Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member   "${MyServiceUserEmail}"
             </powershell>
             <persist>true</persist>
           - MyServiceUserEmail: !Ref ServiceUserEmail
```